# How to store pdf , word and other docs in flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am making a Document Saver app like if i pick a document from my device using file picker and show picked docs using listview its fine.But whenever i reopen the app they are gone.How to keep those docs permanently into my flutter app ?
Here is a short GetFile Function to pick pdf, how to save this picked pdf into app itself?

```
    Future<void> GetFile() async {
    picked = true;
    result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        withReadStream: true,
        allowMultiple: true,
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ['pdf']);
    if (result == null) return;
    setState(() {
      files.addAll(result!.files);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Storing a file in the app itself will not go as an app is no storage location. Further i find it strange that you want to make copies of all files.

Comment: I just want the data to be persistent in my app how can i achieve that ? Also if i will pick some file from my phone then the app will forget it as soon as i close it .Please help regarding this

Comment: Please formulate better what you consider to be 'the data'. What exactly should be remembered. Give an example for one file at least

Comment: Consider 2 PDF files which are in my phone..I pick those files and show in listview in my flutter app that works fine..What i am asking is i want those files to be there whenever i open app next time so i dont want to pick those pdfs again and again

Comment: are you using pdfviewer to view pdf in the listview  Or do you want to show as file name and while click on the file name open that file in adobe pdf or any thirdparty pdfviewer.

Comment: Point is not opening the PDF..i will do that but what i want is those PDFs should remain there in list view whenever i reopen app

Comment: Yes you do not want to pick those files again. We knew already. So you should remember those two files. Now first tell how one can remember a file. On which data? And a listview will not fill automatically. So what should you put in it at startup?